# CSV python module print none from a csv file

Tags: python, csv

I want to read data from a CSV file but my output says field values in the rows are "None". It doesn't recognize the values in my CSV file.

Any ideas ?

Here's the code I am using :

```
import arcpy
import csv
arcpy.env.workspace = "D:"
csvfile             = "D:/file.csv"
domains = []
rows = []

with open(csvfile, 'r') as csvfile:
     reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
     for row in reader:
     try:
        domains.append(row.get('domain'))
        rows.append(row)
    except KeyError:
       rows = [row]

domains = list(set(domains))
print("Identified %s unique domains" % len(domains))
print("Identified %s codes" % len(rows))


print("Creating codes:")
for row in rows:
    print("%s\t%s\t%s" % (row.get('domain'), row.get('code'), row.get('code_description')))
```

Here's a sample of my csv file, very basic and tab delimitated.[image]

And here's the result i am getting :
[image]

Here's the print of the rows:
[image]

Comment: Please fix the indentation. Also, you may want to transform `domains` into a set from the start instead of appending to a list.

Comment: `some_dict.get('some_key')` will never raise a `KeyError`, it will return `None` if it can't find it. try swapping it to `domains.append(row['domain'])`.

Comment: syntax error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from the indentaiton issues, try the following modification:

```py
import arcpy
import csv
arcpy.env.workspace = "D:"
csvfile             = "D:/file.csv"
domains = set()
rows = []

with open(csvfile, 'r') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter=';')
    for row in reader:
        try:
            domains.add(row['domain'])
            rows.append(row)
        except KeyError:
            print("Couldn't parse", row)

print("Identified %s unique domains" % len(domains))
print("Identified %s codes" % len(rows))


print("Creating codes:")
for row in rows:
    print("%s\t%s\t%s" % (row.get('domain'), row.get('code'), row.get('code_description')))
```

Comment: Thank you but there is a syntax error somewhere in your code

Comment: @Mar python version?

Comment: it's a python27

Comment: Python 2.7 reached end of support by january 2020, you should definetely update to python 3. I edited it to remove the python 3.6 addition (we are in 3.8 stable right now), f-strings.

Comment: yes you are right i should update to python 3 eventually. hence your updates are not working, now my csv reactes as it's empty , no results at all !

Comment: Oh you were missing the delimiter. CSV means Comma Separated Values, if you wnat to read values separated by tabs you need to specify that the delimiter is `'\t'` and not the default `','`.

Comment: oh still ! no results at all, it's like the csv file is empty...

Comment: Can you tell me what gets printed in the screen before the number of domains with the current code ( I changed a line)? Also, does your tab separated file have `"` to delimit strings? As you showed a image from a visualizing tool I can't now if the file has them or not.

Comment: The rows are well printed , i will try to share a screen shot of the result.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222224/discussion-between-mar-and-adirio).